# Firebase auth: Only test phone numbers are getting authenticated

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have firebase phone auth set up for my app. Test numbers are working fine but real phone numbers are failing with the following message:

> Auth failed: The format of the phone number provided is incorrect.
> Please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into
> E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are written in the format
> [+][country code][subscriber number including area code].

I tried sending in formats like +918027429274, +91 8027429274, +91 80 27 429 274 etc. but nothing working. Tried passing these formats into the verifyPhoneNumber() method. However any type of test phone numbers are getting through fine. Here's my code:

```
  // verify with phone
  Future verifyPhone({
    required String phoneNumber,
    required void Function(PhoneAuthCredential) verificationCompleted,
    required void Function(FirebaseAuthException) verificationFailed,
    required void Function(String, int?) codeSent,
    required void Function(String) codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
    int? forceResendingToken,
  }) async {
    debugPrint('sending otp to $phoneNumber');
    var num = await PhoneNumberUtil().parse(phoneNumber);
    debugPrint('parsed ${num.international}');
    try {
      _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+918027429274',
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
        forceResendingToken: forceResendingToken,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
        name: 'login_error',
        parameters: {'msg': e.toString()},
      );
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```